# jQuery метод prepend вставляет текст как текстовую строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь добавить элемент в `div` блок:

```
$("#content .contextual")[0].prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>")
```

На выходе получается, что он вставляет элемент как строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Уберите `[0]`. `$("#content .contextual").prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>")`.

Comment: Если нужен первый элемент, используйте [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: @Dmitry, да, это сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае стоит написать так:

```
$("#content .contextual:first").prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>");
```

Или так:

```
$("#content .contextual").first().prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>");
```

---

В чем проблема с оригиналом:

Код `$("#content .contextual")` возвращает jQuery объект.
Конструкция `$("#content .contextual")[0]` же возвращает DOM Element объект.

Соответственно, в первом случае используется [метод prepend из jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), а во втором - [метод prepend для DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend). Эти методы ведут себя по-разному при передаче им строки.

Поэтому проблема не в том, что метод `prepend` в jQuery ведёт себя некорректно, а в том, что вы используете совершенно другой метод `prepend`.

Answer (score 1):

@Regent правильно сказал про то какие объекты возвращают методы

```
1. $("#content .contextual")
2. $("#content .contextual")[0]
```

Дополню ответ:

Если вам нужно будет добавить `html` кусок не в первый или последний элемент с вашим классом `.contextual` а например в третий то можете сделать так:

```js
var $contextual = $("#content .contextual")[3];
$($contextual).prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div class="contextual"></div>
    <div class="contextual"></div>
    <div class="contextual"></div>
    <div class="contextual"></div>
    <div class="contextual"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Вместо получения DOM Element-a и повторной обёртки достаточно использовать метод [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/): `$("#content .contextual").eq(3).prepend("<a href=\"example.com\">example.com</a>");`

Comment: @Regent правильно спасибо.